# How can I export a video to WMV format in Lion?

Tags: macos, quicktime, video

I used to use Flip4Mac, but because QuickTime X doesn’t provide a plug-in mechanism for video exports, Flip4Mac doesn’t work with it.

How do I export videos to WMV in Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this chart from Telestream site](http://www.telestream.net/flip4mac-wmv/tech-specs.htm) you can use Compressor 4, QT7Pro and MPEG Streamclip (never used Episode 6 so don't know what it is). You can probably [install QT7 from here](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl923).

[image]

Comment: Excellent: QuickTime 7 Pro worked a treat. (I had a Pro license handing around from the old days.) I had to restart my Mac after installing QuickTime 7 to make it recognise Flip4Mac WMV Studio (which I already had installed), but after that it worked great.

Comment: Yes it's probably have to be restarted fot plug-ins to be rescaned since QT is system wide